# np.vectorize giving me IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, numpy

trying out something simple and it's frustratingly not working:

```
def myfunc(a,b):
  return a+b[0]

v = np.vectorize(myfunc, exclude=['b'])

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = [0]

v(a,b)
```

This gives me "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable."
Upon printing b, it appears that the b taken in by the function is always 0, instead of [0]. Can I specify which arguments should be vectorized and which should remain constant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `excluded=['b']` the *keyword* parameter `b` is excluded.
Therefore, you must call `v` with keyword arguments, e.g. `v(a=a, b=b)` instead of `v(a, b)`.

If you wish to call `v` with positional arguments with the second positional argument excluded, then use

```
v = np.vectorize(myfunc)
v.excluded.add(1)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(a, b):
    return a+b[0]

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = [0, 1]

v = np.vectorize(myfunc, excluded=['b'])
print(v(a=a, b=b))
# [1 2 3]

v = np.vectorize(myfunc)
v.excluded.add(1)
print(v(a, b))
# [1 2 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already found this out but I marked your answer correct for anyone in the future having this problem.

I bumped into something else weird: When I try something like v(a, b) with the above function, for some reason it takes in the first element of a twice. Like 1+1+2+3 or 0+0+1+2 instead of 1+2+3 or 0+1+2. Any idea what's up?

Comment: `np.vectorize` calls the function one (extra) time to determine the type of output. You can avoid this by specifying the `otypes`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have read the doc in greater detail, remember something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is the answer:

v.excluded.add(1) works, though passing exclude=['b'] does not, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just add print to see what happens:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    print(a, b)
    return a + b

v = np.vectorize(myfunc)

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([0])
v(a, b)
```

Output:

```
1 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
```

The function is applied to all elements of the array. So it receives only scalar values. You cannot index a scalar.

Comment: I already knew that b was being treated as 0 and not [0] as mentioned.

The solution was to add v.excluded.add(1), but thanks for playing I guess.