# Generalised hypergeometric function for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, mpmath

I'm looking to fit some data to the hypergeometric function. I'm using the generalised hypergeometric function given in `mpmath`, `hyper`. I'm trying to convert it to work with `curve_fit` using `np.frompyfunc`. When I do

```
np_hyp = np.frompyfunc(hyper,3,1)
np_hyp([-1/3],[-2/3,2/3],x**2/4)
```

where `x` is some numpy array. The error I get is `len(a_s): 'float' object has no length`, or something to that effect (I'll be more accurate when I can get back to my PC to replicate the error). I suspect it's something to do with the inputs being lists and converting weirdly when `numpy` tries to convert the function.

Does anyone know a way to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: quick guess is that it also iterates over the first two arguments, i.e. `hyper` is called with `-1/3` and not with `[-1/3]`. As the function needs to determine the length to get p and q it tries to get the length of the float -1/3, which causes the error. Is it time critical or can you just write your own wrapper? Or maybe `vectorize` can help with the `excluded` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my comment from above is true, i.e. the first and second list is also decomposed and passed as single element. This is not supposed to happen. The solution is, hence,

```py
from mpmath import hyper
import numpy as np

print( hyper( [ -1 / 3 ],[ -2 / 3, 2 / 3 ], 0.255 ) )

nphyper = np.vectorize( hyper )
nphyper.excluded.add(0)
nphyper.excluded.add(1)

print( 
    nphyper(
        [ -1 / 3 ],
        [ -2 / 3, 2 / 3 ],
        np.array( [ 0.255, 0.257 ] )
    )
)
```

It is not clear from the docs so thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34065729/803359) post, I figured how to exclude positional arguments.

Comment: That's great, thank you! Although I do now have the wonderful error `Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`, which I suspect is due to my using histograms to fit the data, and not your implementation here.

Comment: Fixed that, needed to add .astype('float') to change it from mpf floats